How can I filter "unwanted" pulses coming from the AM demodulation on a microcontroller. The data is encoded in differential Manchester
EDIT AS ASKED: EM4095 Datasheet I use the read only configuration on a custom board.  I am not using CLK/RDY as the bit rate is known, and reduces complexity (it doesn't offer much other than to measure the frequency so you can sample.) Added schematic on the bottom.
I am using an EM4095 as an RFID reader.
This IC demodulate the AM signal from the antenna and outputs on DEMOD_OUT bit the corresponding digital signal. The data that are transmitted are in differential Manchester encoding and the pulse width is known. In my case the half bit period is 240us and full bit period is 480us.
After measuring the DEMOD_OUT signal, I noticed there are some pulses that do not correspond to any of the known periods and they are random. (I had trouble receiving the same pattern of bits after reading the same tag multiple times)

I believe they are false bits coming from the AM demodulation due to low Vsense margins.
Is there any known good algorithm to filter out this pulse and possible correct the data received? (Rejecting is easy but I'm afraid I will lose data.)
For example, I believe in the image, in the time period of the four short pulses it should be two half bit period pulses.
To capture the bits I am using a timer in input capture mode to measure the pulse width.
Block diagram of EM4095:

Expected signal that matches the pulse width:


The sub-questions in your question are trivial or hard to answer literally, but I'm sure that is not what you want. ("I believe ...?" Yes, you believe. -- "Is there any ...?" Yes, there are.) Please [edit] your question to focus more to make your question answerable. For example, you might want to add how you are planning to decode.

Did you consider to oversample? I had such tasks two times in my career, and each time I oversampled by factor 8 or 16. The sampled level made a counter count up and down, respectively. When a certain threshold was reached, the decoder accepted that level for a half bit. In the next step the decoder could synchronize on the detected edges and set the counter to an appropriate start value for the next half bit.

Such signals are generally noisy and have "glitches" that make the usage of timers and capture modes senseless.

@thebusybee how the oversample will solve my issue?

@thebusybee  Also, I am decoding, i measure the time diff between the edges, and if the time the expected and depending of the pulse width, i store bit 0 and bit 1 in my buffer. But in the bits i am reading i can't find a pattern to see what the tag transmitted. There are always some bits different, that it may be from the noise. I thought i may read multiple times and keep the data that appear more times... But I don't know the max length of the data coming from the tag yet.

ICs (ASICs ) may have hacks which dont conform to a standard protocol. The timing of edges doesn't match hardware peripheral timing..

@AmitM i don't see how that is related. the IC to me is functioning as expected, the problem is at the noisy AM signal.

Would you mind to add a link to the data sheet of the EM4095, and the schematic of your circuit?

Also it would help to see the DMOD_IN signal of the same erroneous situation, if to measure it does not interfere too much. And the expected output signal.

The title question asks for MCU filtering, that misled me. But by now, you seem to ask about correcting your EM4095 circuit. Please clarify, and edit the title if appropriate.

@thebusybee modifying the hardware is not an option right now. I changed the title, to what I think is more appropriate. Because data is encoded in Manchester, i wanted to know if it is already an algorithm to "filter" the data. I think filter is a confusing term here, maybe call it correct the data? The thing that the pulses must be around 240us or 480us is what I can use.

The algorithm I implement is that if the time diff calculated in each edge with the previous is not any of the two (240 or 480), then it doesn't take it to account. This somewhat made the data captured more consistent but still they are not always the same. The next thing I think Ill do is to store the data and compare to each other, and keep the ones that apear the most... (maybe some noise coming from the AM is causing close to 240us or 480us pulse?)

It is always a bad idea to use edge interrupts on noisy signals. You will have all sorts of problems. It starts with many interrupts, generally more than your interrupt service routine can handle. It goes on with missed interrupts because they come too fast. And it does not end with a complex algorithm to make sense of the captured times.
The following is a common approach, software only. There are other solutions, which suppress the noise in analog electronics and use a Schmitt trigger, for example. This latter option is here modeled in software.
Sample the signal at an appropriate rate. Because such an appropriate rate is a multiple of the frequency of the signal, it is called "oversampling", you sample more than once in a half bit interval. The linked Wikipedia page mentions average sums, but you can make it simpler.
Please look at the extended copy of your picture. I have used the raster of your oscilloscope as the sample rate (light blue). The red dots on your yellow signal mark the sampled levels. The red line shows the value of a saturating counter. It counts up, if the sample is high. It counts down, if the sample is low. It never counts below zero. It never counts above five.

There are two thresholds, at 4 while counting up, and at 1 while counting down. If the counter counts up and reaches 4, it decides that the input signal is steady high. If the counter counts down and reaches 1, it decides that the input signal is steady low. The gray signal is the result. Yes, it has a delay. Removing noise is paid by this delay.
The shown sample rate of 12 samples per bit interval is most probably not enough, depending on the noise you have. Use a higher rate with a lot of noise, it the end it's all statistics. To sample at regular intervals, use a standard timer interrupt. Keep the interrupt service routine short, forward the bits and do not try to decode the message in it.
With a higher sample rate you need to adjust the thresholds. Make sure they have a difference, because you need hysteresis.
To decode the bits and finally the message, you can use a finite state machine. Even if you think you don't have such, actually you will have it. So it pays to learn more about them.
You don't need to use a capturing timer now, because you can trace the timing in the sampling. I'll leave the decoding of half and full bits as an exercise to you.

thanks for the detailed oversampling explanation. I added some picture in my original post, the EM4095 block diagram and the expected signal that matches the pulse width i expected base of the RFID tag configuration. I think your approach is better if the noise in the digital signal. The digital signal is not noisy in my case but the input of the EM4095, and it generate some false pulses. The width of the section with the false pulses, if we eliminate them, doesn't match any of the expected bit periods.

:-D So you made me spend a good part of my spare time just because you omitted information? (See my comment at your question.) Well, I hope it will help other future visitors at least.

yeah i felt bad as soon as i show your answer :) .  But i thought i was missing something that's why i ask how oversample will help me.

@arisk4 It's alright, don't worry. (And you'll do better the next time, I'm sure.)

You probably can feed that AM signal directly to a small ADC that has a built-in variable input gain, and then demodulate it in software or in the FPGA that may be a part of the SoC. It gives much more flexibility, if you have the CPU cycles or logic resources available for it.
